# Copy varchar column data to date column

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2017 and I have a table with a column of `varchar` type but the value is a date, i.e `'dd/mm/yyyy'`, and I need to convert this to a date value column.

I attempted a straight `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN` like this:

```
USE <databasename>

ALTER TABLE <the_table_name> 
    ALTER COLUMN [column name] date;
GO
```

But the output is an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

I added a new column `[AltColumnName]` with the intention of copying over the column values with an `UPDATE` statement, and then renaming the columns but so far all forms of `UPDATE` I try fails with the same "conversion failed" message.

How do I copy over the `varchar` column values to the date column?

Comment: There is a high probability of values that are not actual dates or that do not follow your formatting assumptions. Use TRY_CONVERT to find those and figure out how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming* that all rows are `dd/MM/yyyy` and are **valid**.

First you need to change your value to an ISO format, we're going to use `yyyyMMdd`

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET DateColumn = CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,DateColumn,103),112);
```

Then you can `ALTER` your table:

```
ALTER dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN DateColumn date;
```